# How to check if an alignment is valid in C?

Tags: c, memory-alignment, c11

The code I am writing needs to be fully standard compliant. The standard does not promise any alignment options stronger than that of `max_align_t`. I want to try to align to a cache line, but I understand that to be undefined behavior if the implementation does not support alignments of that strength.

Is there any way around this? Any ways to check at preprocessing what extended alignments are available? Or are there any ways to ask for an alignment, and just not get it, rather than have undefined behavior, if the alignment is not available?

`aligned_alloc` works for allocated memory. However, I am also interested in statically stored memory.

EDIT:
To illustrate my problem, here are the statements from the C11 standard I have problems with:

> 6.2.8
>
> 4. Alignments are represented as values of the type `size_t`. Valid alignments include only those values returned by an `_Alignof` expression for fundamental types, plus an additional implementation-defined set of values, which may be empty. Every valid alignment value shall be a nonnegative integral power of two.

So any given 2 power is not necesarily a valid alignment, and I can't count on 64 to be less than or equal to `max_align_t`, and so 64 may not be a valid alignment. If it is not a valid alignment, here is my undefined behavior issue:

> 6.7.5 Alignment specifier
>
> 3. The constant expression shall be an integer constant expression. It shall evaluate to a valid fundamental alignment, or to a valid extended alignment supported by the implementation in the context in which it appears, or to zero.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, expecially as you used the C11 tag. `_Alignas_` uses the alignment you specify. If you use an illegal alignment you invoke UB, but it still is used for the object. What is the problem? And preprocessing is done before the processing (look up the prefix "pre"), so how would that come into the game?

Comment: The problem is the undefined behavior. I need to garantee that there will be no undefined behavior, and so I can't align to an alignment that has a chance of producing undefined behavior. There is no garantee that something as benign as 64 will be a legal alignment.

Comment: Ehm, you should read about the idea about alignment. Can you elaborate why a larger multiple of the required alignment would be a problem?

Comment: 1. The preprocessor is definitely not going to help. 2. If *_Alignas_* doesn't do what you want, you can always allocate (also statically) a larger memory block and work inside that aligned to addresses to your taste. This is entirely compiler and system independent. Whether that improves readability and maintainability of your code, I'll leave to you... In most cases you'll be better off using dynamic memory and *aligned_alloc()*

Comment: @tofro 1. I was hoping to use the preprocessor to drop my alignment request if I can determine it will not produce defined behavior. For example, if max_align_t where 64 byte aligned (which I doubt would ever be), then I could use that information to prove that my 64 byte alignment can be included. 2. The code of interest is a header that declares many similar functions that I want using the same memory, and I want it cache line aligned, both for performance considerations. Allocating would introduce an undesired complication in using the functions.

Comment: @tofro, as for working inside a larger block of static memory, that would still require initialization, and I don't want any special initialization or clean up necessary for these functions.

Comment: In this case you're telling us: "I want something from the language and the language doesn't support it". You want it standard-compliant, but not inducing extra work - You need to tell the language committee, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No alignment that your compiler will chose by its own should be wider than `max_align_t`, but that is all that there is to it. There is no interdiction for asking for a wider alignment.

So to ensure that a specific field of a `struct` lays on a boundary as you wish, you'd just have to use `_Alignas`. All is well-defined as long as the value that you are asking for is a power of 2, and the particular alignment is allowed by your compiler. If it isn't, you compiler *must* complain.

This is exactly one of the reasons `_Alignas` has been added in C11.

Comment: Just for an alignment to be a 2 power does not suffice for a valid alignment. I'm adding the quotes from the standard to my question to support that. So, my problem is that I would like to just ask for a 2 power, and if it is not provided, then fine. That is probably what the undefined behavior would amount to. Nonetheless, I still would be relying on undefined behavior, and that is not acceptable for my project.

Comment: No, a "shall" in a standards text in general names a constraint. So if the alignment that you chose is not among the extended alignments, your compiler *must* give a diagnostic. In particular, such code will either compile (and then the behavior is well defined) or compilation will fail with a diagnostic. If you think of it, it makes no sense to have "undefined behavior" here. Types and their alignment are a compile time feature. So if something is wrong the compiler should tell you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't realize that the "shall"s placed such well defined requirements on the implementation. I found the description of those requirements in the standard, so that is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you needed see functions **valloc()** or **memalign()**.
Also, very useful call:

```
int pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
```

If you needed align buffer with pagesize, you can call:

```
char *buf = ...; // Buffer to unaligned memory
buf -= (uinsigned)buf & (pagesize - 1); // align to low border
buf += pagesize; // align to high border
```

Comment: Whatever `uinsigned` is, that is a very bad (and unnecessary) hack. OP clearly asks about a standard-compliant way, which your code is definitively not. And he primarily asks about static objects.